# how to call function every 10sec in php using shell script?

Tags: php, shell

How to call function every 5sec using shell script. Is there any way to call function in every 5sec?

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ true ]
do
sh special_svn_script.sh
sleep 10
done
```

Comment: you can creates cron job to execute php script every one minute or any time interval you set.

Comment: change `sleep 10` to `sleep 5` ?

Comment: Please can you explain your problem more clearly? What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: @HirendrasinhS.Rathod yes currently i'm using that but i want to in shell script

Comment: @ashishmulani use watch -n 5 <your shell script>>

Comment: What is wrong with the code you provided i your question?